# unchecked is not working

Tags: c#, overflow, underflow

I was just trying some of the samples question in c# and came through the follwing problem

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        { return a + b; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte myByte = 200;
            byte myInt = 100;
            byte ans;
            unchecked
            {
                ans = Convert.ToByte(myByte + myInt);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Value of myByte: {0}", myByte);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

In the above case even if the underflow/overflow happens inside unchecked block , its throwing an exception . 
Please help .

Comment: y r u converting byte to byte ?

Comment: i am learning c# , so just trying some odd scenario .

Comment: it is not possible to assign an integer to byte.
byte myInt = 300; will give exception on compile time.

Comment: ya , got it .. Thanks . Question has been edited .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood `unchecked` block. It only checks when simply an **expression** which results in a overflow or underflow.

In your case you're calling `Convert.ToByte` method. That method can throw whatever exception it wants. That has no relation with `unchecked` block.

Your example is not valid `byte  myInt = 300;` won't compile. Try this, It won't throw exception, because we use expressions.

```
byte myByte = 0;
int myInt = 300;
unchecked
{
    myByte = (byte)(myInt + myByte);
}
```

Also note that `unchecked` is default in c#, so you don't need to explicitly say `unchecked`

---

To make it more clear let's create our own method

```
private static void DoSomething(int a, int b)
{
    throw new OverflowException();
}

unchecked
{
    DoSomething(1,2);
}
```

So what you expect here? `OverflowException` to be thrown or CLR should eat your exception?

Comment: so unchecked is applicable only in case of arithmatic expression ?

Comment: @jensar Yes, you got it.

Comment: In your recent edited answer , when you pass 1,2 in DoSomething() function which datatype it is taking .
I ran the example you have given and its throwing an exception .

Comment: Yes it will throw an exception. I added it just to make you clear that Methods can throw `OverflowException` even when it is in `unchecked` block.

Comment: `throw new OverflowException();` is saying throw the exception, so it is throwing. Read about [throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx) keyword.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42301/discussion-between-jensar-and-sriram-sakthivel)